# Nomad periodic doesn't run bash script

Tags: bash, nomad

I have this periodic task below in nomad. The purpose is to run a script on host `nomad3` every 5 minutes. I've also included the contents of the script below.

```
job "periodic" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]

  type = "batch"

  periodic {
    cron             = "*/5 * * * * *"
    prohibit_overlap = true
    time_zone        = "UTC"
  }

  group "periodic" {
    count = 1

    restart {
      interval = "5m"
      attempts = 10
      delay    = "25s"
      mode     = "delay"
    }

    task "cronjob-test" {
      driver = "exec"

      constraint {
        attribute = "${node.unique.name}"
        value = "nomad3"
      }

      config {
        command = "/bin/bash"
        args = ["/usr/local/bin/cronjob-test.sh"]
      }

      resources {
        cpu = 100 # Mhz
        memory = 10 # MB

        network {
          mbits = 10

          # Request for a dynamic port
          port "uptime" {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with the `cronjob-test.sh` containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DATE=$(date '+%F-%s')
touch /tmp/$DATE
```

The script is on nomad host `nomad3`. I'm supposed to see a file in `/tmp` with the format I indicated in the bash script but I'm not seeing this. Need help on what is going on.

Comment: I've already included the script in the post. It's below the nomad job definition.

Comment: yes, if you look at the job definition, it's an absolute path to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was using the `exec` driver which is chrooted. I tried using `raw_exec` and it worked. I then re-tried using `exec` by adding the target directory in the `chroot_env` in the configuration and it worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

The below script will create a 0 byte file under /tmp:-

```
DATE=$(date '+%F-%s')
touch /tmp/$DATE //file name would be 2018-04-04-%s
```

Check your DATE variable whether it is correctly set. Just add a echo command like $DATE and check whether that is accepted or not.

Comment: That's odd. In my environment, it creates a 0 byte file like so: `-rw-rw-r--  1 vagrant vagrant    0 Apr  4 11:11 2018-04-04-1522840263`

Comment: if it is creating a 0 byte file `2018-04-04-1522840263` it is working fine. Your script will simply do that only.

Comment: But the problem is: it's not creating that file. I was expecting this with the nomad periodic job.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
config {
    command = "/bin/bash"
    args = ["-c"，"/usr/local/bin/cronjob-test.sh"]
  }
```